# nxlog fails to connect, and never retries

Tags: windows, vagrant, udp, nxlog

I'm having an issue with nxlog, when trying to connect over network. It seems it is linked with misconfigured network (this is on a virtual machine, within Vagrant)

Error message is

> ERROR couldn't connect to udp socket on 192.168.41.2:514; A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.

Unfortunately, it never tries to reconnect; i've seen there's an option to reconnect in configuration file, but only for ssl and tcp, and it is deprecated.

I failed to find details in forums and documentations - is there something I can do to force reconnect (or detect misconnection?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the `om_udp` module of the NXLog Community Edition. We have already fixed this in the EE and the fix will be available in the next CE release also.